# Вопрос с js и удаление строк

Tags: javascript

Суть заключается в следующем, имеются div контенты, их 50 штук (`<div class="1"><div>123</div><div>456</div>...</div>`), мне нужно удалить 3 div контента из последних строк, как такую функцию можно реализовать?

Comment: Дайте пример, опишите входные данные и данные, которые ожидаете получить на выходе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать можно вот так, как пример [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/jdjjcLs7/10/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
Удалить последние 3 записи: <button>Удалить!</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // тестовое наполнение контентом
  var content = $("#content");
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    content.append("<div>" + i + "</div>");
  }

  // реализация удаления последних трёх div
  $("button").on("click",function(){
    $.each(content.children().slice(-3),function(i,d){
        d.remove();
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо